# How to multiprocess lots of small tasks

Tags: python, parallel-processing, multiprocessing, python-multiprocessing

I have array of 1000-2000 lists, and I need to pass each of that list into function. Each function call takes approximately 0.002s.
I already tried using concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor and multiprocessing Pool. Each of that approach is 1.5x-2x slower than simply iterate over big array in a linear one-process way.
Also, I've tried splitting big array of lists into several smaller arrays of lists, but, it isn't done job faster too, only slower.
I assume, the reason behind that is switching between processes, but, theoreticly, splitting big array into chunks should've been fix that.

Is there any way to do this faster?

Lists are lines of image (numpy arrays) with values 0 or 255 (black and white pixels)

Function is detecting indexes of ranges of black lines on single line

```
[0, 0, 0, 255, 255, 0, 255, 255,255] -> ((0, 2), (5, 5))
```

Code for testing (objects_on_line needs to be parallel):

```
import numpy as np
from time import perf_counter
import cv2

OBJ_COLOR = 0

def chunks(lst, n):
    """Yield successive n-sized chunks from lst."""
    for i in range(0, len(lst), n):
        yield tuple(lst[i:i + n].tolist())

def objects_on_line(line):
    line_original = np.array(line)
    line = np.where(line_original==OBJ_COLOR)[0]
    mask=[0]*len(line)

    for i, el in enumerate(line[:-1]):
        if line[i+1] - el == 1 and (i+2 < len(line) and line[i+2] - el == 2):
            mask[i+1] = 1

    line = np.ma.array(line, mask=mask).compressed()

    i = 0
    for _ in line[:-1]:
        if i+1 >= len(line):
            break

        lv = line[i]
        ls = line_original[lv:line[i+1]]

        if len(np.where(ls != OBJ_COLOR)[0]) != 0:
            line = np.insert(line, i, lv)

        i += 2

    if len(line) % 2 != 0:
        line = np.insert(line, len(line), line[-1])

    line = list(chunks(line, 2))

    return line



img = cv2.cvtColor(cv2.imread("test_people.png"), cv2.COLOR_RGB2GRAY)
img_bin = cv2.threshold(img, 128, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)

s = perf_counter()

for line in img_bin:
    objects_on_line(line)

print(f"Done in: {perf_counter()-s}")
```

Comment: Amdahl's law tells you that processes that are overwhelmed by overhead are not going to parallelize well. It's hard to know for sure without some code we can run.

Comment: What's the function? And what are the lists like?

Comment: You may try to do something with NumPy, depending on what your function does.

Comment: Looks like this can be done faster without multiprocessing. How long are the lists? Can you share code to generate realistic data for testing?

Comment: Why do you have lists? Can you load the image as NumPy arrays instead?

Comment: @KellyBundy they are NumPy arrays, as I've mentioned at the end of the post

Comment: Then you'd probably get much better answers if you tagged this with numpy instead of multiprocessing and didn't say "list" when they're not lists.

Comment: One important thing to note: numpy, being implemented in C, uses thread-based parallelism. When you mix thread-based parallelism and process-based parallelism, numpy will try to use the maximum number of threads by default _in each process_ which can make processing slower than a single process.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ```
> line_original = np.array(line)
> ```

Don't do that. Change the API you define, so there is
an `objects_on_lines(image: np.array, lines: tuple[int])` function.

You want to put all the image pixels into
a single numpy array and then *leave them there*.
Pass in a `(start, end)` range of indexes
for a core to chew on.
(Heck, you could even pass in a `range` object.)

Avoid copying into a newly created list.
Just use the pixels where they are.
Point at them with indexes.

It's not clear that your system will be able
to achieve 12x speedup, even if coded
in Rust or C++. It might be the case that
a handful of cores can max out your
main memory bandwidth.
Increasing the multiprogramming level beyond
that, to 12 or 24, would be counter productive.

Take care to represent pixels compactly.
At least use `uint8`.
If possible use a bit vector,
for an 8x reduction in memory bandwidth
requirements.

---

Consider staggering your offsets within
the array. If all threads are hitting
virtual memory addresses which conflict
for the same cache line, then with
4-way associativity there's a fairly
low limit on how many threads can
productively contend for fresh pixels.

---

There's something called "the straggler
effect". Your N identical cores won't
necessarily be scheduled and perform
identically. It's likely that at least
one will complete its task after the
others. So rather than breaking 2000
lists into N same-size lists, consider
breaking out N "large" plus a
couple of "small" lists. Begin working
on the large lists initially. Then if
a core is done with a large list early, it
will find a small list to work on,
overlapping with the work done by some
straggler core.

---

Table lookups may help to speed your
edge detection. Suppose each raster of
bits is encoded in uint8 bytes, 2 bits
at a time. Now there are four cases:

- `00`, no object
- `01`, found the left edge
- `10`, found the right edge
- `11`, all object

Combine a bunch of 2-bit results
to find the result for a whole raster.

More usefully, you might store > 2 bits
per array element. Four bits leads to a
16-entry lookup table. You might want to
filter salt & pepper noise from entries,
e.g. viewing `0101` (half object?) as `0111` (mostly object!).

A more efficient approach of 8 pixels
per byte leads to a 256-entry lookup table.

---

If these pixels come from webcam video
frames, it might be useful to filter
current frame based on what was seen
in previous frame on same raster,
at least if there's some amount of
horizontal object motion appearing in
the feed.
Then your lookup table is indexed on
both `prev` and `cur` pixel values.

Answer (score 0):

Your only option is to rewrite the function to accept more elements and reword the algorithm to reduce wasted work.

Comment: I've tried that by writing wrapping function that takes several lists and applies original function to them. In general, this splitted big array into chunks.

So, after that, i've splitted big array into 12 chunks (my machine has 12 cores) and fed those chunks into wrapping function in parallel, but it still was 1.5x times slower.